# Http request failing when used with listview

Tags: android, listview, httprequest

I'm a beginner in android and I've got a problem with http request in combination with listview.

First things first. I wrote an app that requested data from this url: "https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/40053".

Everything works; I get a json file, parse it and get the current value of all datastreams, great. However I showed the values on a normal textview and decided I want to view it in a listview.

Made another app with a listview and got it working. Then I integrated my httprequest code only to find out it fails, my app crashes. I thought it might've something to do with the array i'm creating from the json data, but turns out it doesn't even come that far.

I honestly have no idea what to do anymore, please help!

Comment: post the stack trace always if you have any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have forgotten to use the Internet permission in your app's manifest?

Comment: .... =D ty. Is there any way I can see I'm missing certain permissions? I use eclipse.

Comment: Open the AndroidManifest.xml. Inside of the <manifest>-element you have to insert <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />